# Is BigDecimal usable in Codename one?

Tags: codenameone

Is BigDecimal usable in CodenameOne? I'm getting wrong values. For example, here's a block of code, along with the output it produces:

```
private static void testBigDecimal() {
  BigDecimal bdOne = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE, 0);

  final BigInteger iTen = new BigInteger("10");
  BigDecimal bdTen = new BigDecimal(iTen, 0);
  printValues(bdOne, bdTen, iTen, 0);

  BigDecimal bdOne1 = bdOne.adjustScale(1);
  BigDecimal bdTen1 = bdTen.adjustScale(1);
  printValues(bdOne1, bdTen1, iTen, 1);

  BigDecimal bdOne4 = bdOne.adjustScale(4);
  BigDecimal bdTen4 = bdTen.adjustScale(4);
  printValues(bdOne4, bdTen4, iTen, 4);
}

private static void printValues(BigDecimal one, BigDecimal ten, BigInteger iTen, int scale) {
  System.out.println("Scale = " + scale);
  System.out.println("One:  " + one);
  System.out.println("Ten:  " + ten);
  System.out.println("1/10: " + one.divide(ten) + " (divide by BigDecimal");
  System.out.println("1/10: " + one.divide(iTen) + " (divide by BigInteger)");
  System.out.println("");
}
```

So I'm creating values of 1 and 10, and I'm dividing one by ten. I'm dividing by both BigDecimal and BigInteger. And I'm doing this at three different scales. Here are my results:

```
Scale = 0
One:  1
Ten:  10
1/10: 0 (divide by BigDecimal
1/10: 0 (divide by BigInteger)

Scale = 1
One:  1.0
Ten:  10.0
1/10: 0.0 (divide by BigDecimal
1/10: 0.0 (divide by BigInteger)

Scale = 4
One:  1.0000
Ten:  10.0000
1/10: 0.0001 (divide by BigDecimal
1/10: 0.0001 (divide by BigInteger)
```

So sometimes dividing one by ten gives me zero, and other times it gives me 0.0001! Am I doing something terribly wrong? Or does the BigDecimal class need some serious debugging?

Comment: I tried to adapt your code to Java SE to compare it to the reference implementation and it seems that the JavaSE port doesn't support dividing decimals by integers. Also adjust scale isn't publicly exposed. Can you provide a sample that shows how we diverge from the JavaSE behavior for this?

Comment: According to the library I'm using, adjustScale is a public method. I used it because I couldn't find any other way to create a BigDecimal for "1.0000". Also, I see this behavior regardless of whether I divide by a BigDecimal or a BigInteger. As for you request, I'm not sure what you mean by "how we diverge from the Java SE behavior." I called this method from the init() method in the CodenameOne simulator, just to test my code that uses BigDecimal. Are you saying I will get different results when I run it on an actual device?

Comment: I'm seeing other problems with BigDecimal as well. If I do this:

      final BigInteger iTen = new BigInteger("10");
  BigDecimal twoPtFive = new BigDecimal(iTen, 2);

I get a value of 2.10 instead of 2.50.

Comment: — deleted— see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a really old version of the CodenameOne libs?  I get the following when I run your code:

```
Scale = 0
One:  1
Ten:  10
1/10: 0.1 (divide by BigDecimal
1/10: 0.1 (divide by BigInteger)
```

Scale = 1
One:  1.0
Ten:  10.0
1/10: 0.1 (divide by BigDecimal
1/10: 0.1 (divide by BigInteger)

Scale = 4
One:  1.0000
Ten:  10.0000
1/10: 0.1 (divide by BigDecimal
1/10: 0.1000 (divide by BigInteger)

Try updating your libs and see if you get a different result.

Comment: According to the folks at CodenameOne, I should get an updated library when I send a build. So I tried that, but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Are you using an old plugin? Which IDE are you using? FYI @steve-hannah works for us too

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ 15.0.3, and I just disabled the previous plug-in (which I installed only six months ago) and downloaded and installed a new one. The project was created under the previous plugin.

Comment: I may as well add that my CodenameOne.jar file is dated Nov 24, 2015 9:25 pm